# Bootstrap v4.4.1 d-md-none hides item on large screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap v4.4.1 cards to show 3 cards on large screen and hide  and show 2 cards on medium screen. I am using `d-md-none` class to hide 3rd card on md screen but it hide 3rd card on all screen.

Not sure what i am doing wrong.

```
<div class="container  mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6">
        <div class="card" >
          <img src="images/trophy.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6">
        <div class="card" >
          <img src="images/trophy.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="col-xl-4 d-md-none">
        <div class="card" >
          <img src="images/trophy.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/KGuide/pen/rNVZKmE

Answer (score 1):

Add class `d-none d-lg-block`

```
<div class="col-xl-4 d-none d-lg-block">
```

Comment: so we have to use combination of both... i thought it was otherwise